# is there any method which ask user permission to access file without using file picker in winrt

Tags: windows-runtime

I am working on an app which maintain audio notes, each note consist of 2 files, xml file and mp3 file. So when user tries to open file through file picker he selects only xml file and mp3 file need to be access through code. How can i solve this problem?  I need a method which ask user to allow access to another file(mp3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I am quite sure that if the file isn't in one of the local folder, you won't be able to open it without the user selecting it first in the File picker.

You should consider packaging your xml & mp3 file in a zip file for instance, and using the classes in `System.IO.Compression` to retrieve them.

Furthermore, it would be easier to use for your users than having to make sure that both files are on the same folder.

Comment: can u pls give a code to compress two files into one. Thank you